# Python library to discover a C code block by its line number

Tags: python

I have a C program source files and some number associated with them I wanted entire block of code associated with that line number. Example :

```
1.  int i;
2. 
3.  #pragma joe
4.
5.  int main() {
6.    int a = 1;
7.   #pragma inmain
8.
9.   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
10.   #pragma infor
11.      a += i;
12.  }
13.
14.   return a;
15. }
```

If line 11, then block from line 9 to 12 should be returned If line 14, then block from line 5 to 15 should be returned

If any python library exists that can help me with this would be very useful. I tried to use data stack to find previous and next braces that didn't work for all scenarios.